# Wild cards in azure cli script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

How can use wildcards in azure cli?

I have the following that i want to have in my azure cli script:

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip
```

As it is now, I have the following path in my azure cli:

```
$artifactfolder = '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)' + '\_TestApi\drop\TestApi.zip'
```

So how can I use the approach with the wild card insstead?

Here is my CLI script:

```
$resourceGroup = "Test"
$appServicePlan = "brajzoreappserviceplan"
$appServiceName = "brajzoreappservice2"
$artifactFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)" + "\**\*.zip"

az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $appServiceName --src $artifactfolder
```

I get the following error when I run the script:

```
2021-03-12T07:47:10.5624737Z Get-ChildItem : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '\**\*.zip'.
2021-03-12T07:47:10.5627860Z At D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1615535200528_inlinescript.ps1:9 char:19
2021-03-12T07:47:10.5629171Z + $artifactFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\a\r1\a" + "\**\*.zip"
2021-03-12T07:47:10.5630150Z +                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2021-03-12T07:47:10.5630966Z     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
2021-03-12T07:47:10.5632192Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
2021-03-12T07:47:10.5633181Z  
2021-03-12T07:47:10.6016965Z ##[error]Script failed with exit code: 1
```

Comment: Please share your CLI script and the purpose you want to achieve.

Comment: @CharlesXu: Check my updated questions.

Comment: Try `$artifactFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\*\*\*.zip"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error shows it's not an acceptable argument '***.zip'. And according to the [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1#example-4--get-child-items-using-the-include-parameter) here for the command `Get-ChildItem`, it should be like this:

```
$artifactFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\*\*\*.zip"
```